# Where is the formatting of Magento transactional emails applied?

Tags: email, magento, text, format, transactional

I've set up some Magento autoresponders, they all look fine when previewed in admin  Transactional emails. However, when they are actually sent to a customer the formatting is different to that of the preview, font size and type varies for different paragraphs within the email - it looks a mess!

There must be css or similar applied at another level, problem is I don't know where or how.

Our Magento was set up by a developer and I'm not convinced that best practices have been followed.

Can anyone shed any light please?
Thanks in advance.
RobH

Comment: CSS for transactional emails has to go inline. It must therefore be referenced in either the template file or perhaps through a common static block that's been applied to all your emails.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is no ref in my template so it must be applied as static block. My problem, as a Magento newby, is how to identify where this block is located and how it's applied. Cheers H

Answer (score 0):

Email templates will be in `app/locale/en_US/template/email/`

You can customize them from backend system->transactional emails,

These links may be useful for you :

http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/06/customize-new-order-email-template-in.html

https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-theming/1670-customizing-magento-email-templates

http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/customizing-magento-transactional-emails/

http://www.gemgento.com/blog/customizing-magento-order-emails

Read comments as well.

Cheers :-)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your input. I don't have a problem with editing the email templates, the problem appears to be a css style or some other program deciding what font the email uses. I've explicitly specified the font family, size etc for each paragraph of my email and it still totally ignores my html and makes it look messy. Cheers, H!

Answer (score 0):

I've now fixed the problem, posting it here in case it helps any other frustrated amateurs (like me!).

The system templates mostly appear to have an extra " in the h1 tag, this was causing the h1 tag to be applied to the entire body text when creating custom transactional emails. See the middle section of the code below, 11px 0;""

h1 style="font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;"">Hello, {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()}} /h1

Cheers
H

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I'd stupidly ignored the 'Template Styles' details, it was empty for the templates that were displaying really badly. I've now included the basic

```
body,td { color:#2f2f2f; font:12px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
```

info that the rest of the templates seeed to be using. It's better but still not how I want it.

Can anyone advise where this default style can be edited to reduce text size please? I still don't really understand what's going on :-\

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.